# ¿Cómo sumo los valores de un conjunto de hash dentro de un array en ruby?

Tags: ruby

Tengo un array `personas[]` que dentro contiene los datos de muchas personas, en cada hash, o sea cada persona tiene su hash. Quiero sumar los valores de todas las edades, e intentado con varias cosas sin resultados.

```
persona = {nombre:a, edad:b, comuna:c, género:d }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay que añadir, que Ruby a partir de la versión `2.4` añade el método [`Enumerable#sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum), que como el nombre indica, suma todos los elementos de un `Enumerable`:

```
personas = [
  { nombre: 'hugo', edad: 8 },
  { nombre: 'paco', edad: 9 },
  { nombre: 'luis', edad: 10 }
]

personas.sum { |persona| persona[:edad] }
#=> 27
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes sumar las edades así:

```
#Array de Personas
personas = [ 
             { nombre: 'hugo', edad: 8 }, 
             { nombre: 'paco', edad: 9 }, 
             { nombre: 'luis', edad: 10},
           ]

personas.map { |persona| persona[:edad] }.inject(:+)
# => 27
```

Esto funciona así:

Primero tienes el array `personas` que contiene los hashes de cada persona, luego iteramos en ese array utilizando el método `map` para obtener la edad de cada persona con `persona[:edad]` y finalmente aplicamos `inject(:+)` que va a sumar todos los valores que pasamos, en este caso, todas las edades.

Comment: Y si deseo saber el promedio?

Comment: Ya lo saque gracias,

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción es utilizar `reduce` (o `inject`) con un bloque, lo cual es más eficiente ya que se recorre el arreglo únicamente una vez:

```
personas  = [
  { nombre: "hugo", edad: 8 },
  { nombre: "paco", edad: 9 },
  { nombre: "luis", edad: 10 }
]

personas.reduce(0) { |sum, persona| sum += persona[:edad] }
#=> 27
```